# VB.NET Rich TextBox Newline Character removal

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am using a Rich TextBox in VB.NET and passing to a StringBuilder. I need to replace the New Line character from the TextBox with either a space or a comma. Problem is the standard codes for new line don't seem to be picking up this New Line character in this case. Is there a specific character used in Rich TextBoxes as the New Line? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. You have to use ControlChars.Lf so the code would be along the lines of the following:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, ",")
```

Comment: Ah yes, ControlCharacters. I completely forgot about those since I have been working almost exclusively in C# for a good while now. Glad you solved it!

Comment: By the way, ControlChars.Lf is equivalent to Chr(10), as ezwi and I mentioned earlier :)

Comment: Again, however, this is a VB-specific function. Why not use Environment.Newline so that it's language agnostic?

Comment: Actually had tried environment.newline with no success. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Note that this removes all formatting from the **rich**textbox.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `Environment.NewLine` as a language-agnostic constant for a true newline (you should try to avoid language-specific constants and functions when possible).

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the RichTextBox's Lines property.  You could then insert your commas or however you're delimiting it as follows

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder(String.Join(",", Me.richTextBox1.Lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim linesJoined As String = String.Join(",", Me.RichTextBox1.Lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just `chr(10)` or `chr(13)`. `VbCrLf` is a combination of both `chr(10)` and `chr(13)`.

Try parsing out one or the other, and see if that helps.